# Extra width and height with 100%

Tags: css

I have some issues with header and other divs, for a reason I get an extra space
I don't want to use `overflow:hidden`, I want to remove the space, not to hide it..I tried to set the body and html height but it didn't work as well, maybe I have to deal with `position:`

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}
#header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:#D3790B;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

#chater{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 52px;  /* distanta dintre header si chatbar*/
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 250px;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background-image:url("../images/1.png");;
    border-right: 2px solid #D3790B;
}

#navtab {
    position: absolute;
    top:52px; /* distanta dintre header si navtab*/
    left:252px;
    width: 73px;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url("../images/1.png");;
    bottom:0px;

}

.tab {
    height:78px;
    width: 78px;
    display:flex;

}

#slidebar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 4px;
    height: 78px;
    background-color: darkorange;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#slider {
    width:4px;
    height:100%;
    background: black;
    position:absolute;
    left:325px;
    top:52px;


}

.icons {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    top:25px;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
}

.ctab {

    position:absolute;
    top:52px;
    left:329px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:none;
}

.selected {
    display: block;
    display: initial;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="chater"></div>
<div id="slider"><div id="slidebar"></div></div>
<div id="navtab">
    <div class="tab c1"><img src="/images/icons/jackpot.png" class="icons"></div>
    <div class="tab c2"><img src="/images/icons/mines.png" class="icons"></div>
    <div class="tab c3"><img src="/images/icons/roll1.png" class="icons"></div>
    <div class="tab c4"><img src="/images/icons/wallet.png" class="icons"></div>
    <div class="tab c5"><img src="/images/icons/transfer.png" class="icons"></div>
</div>
<div class="ctab tab_1 selected"> Content 1</div>
<div class="ctab tab_2"> Content 2</div>
<div class="ctab tab_3">Content 3</div>
<div class="ctab tab_4">Content 4</div>
<div class="ctab tab_5">Content 5</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gtq5co2a/

Answer (score 0):

When you have borders or padding, those add to the element's width (i.e., by default `width` just talks about the width of the "inside stuff" — the actual content area).

You want to add:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

With the border-box model, `width` describes the ***entire*** width, including padding and borders, with whatever remains being leftover for content.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your

```
<div class="ctab tab_1 selected"> Content 1</div>
```

If you comment out the absolute position and the left value

```
.ctab {
   /*position: absolute;*/
   top: 52px;
   /* left: 329px; */
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;       
}
```

then the extra space disapears.

I don't understand why you are absolutely positioning almost every element though - that seems like you're setting yourself up for more headaches than necessary.

**EDIT**

Here is a fiddle with no extra space at all
https://jsfiddle.net/f81py7ky/2/

In addition to the above changes i commented our your selected class. Your content isn't showing but now you know what your culprit is, although i still think all the absolute positions is going to be a problem for you.

Comment: there's still height space